# jquery datepicker not display on my django project

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to display a datepicker on my web little project with the help of django frame.
The case is that when I do the request to my page it displays everithing ok, but the datepicker calendar do not pop-up.

Could you help me? My code is:

My class:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class clientcheckform(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = client
    fields = ('checkin',)
    widgets = {
        'checkin': forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d%m%Y',attrs={
            'class':'input',
            'readonly':'readonly',
            'size':'15',
        })
    }
```

My view.py --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def index(request):
    client_check = clientcheckform()                                    

template = loader.get_template('booking/index.html')
context = Context({
    'client_check': client_check,
     })
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

To display I am using this template:---------------------------------------------------

```
<p><b></br>Select CheckIn Day: </b></p>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="/media/css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#checkin').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
</script>
</head>
{{client_check}}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks. Victor.

Comment: Please, show the html you get on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"jQuery is not defined" means jQuery.js is not loaded.

From looking at your code, it is probably one of the following two reasons:

1. The incorrect HTML markup. Try to take away the `<head>` tag around `<script>` and `<link>`.
2. The jQuery file included has incorrect path or the file itself is corrupted. Try to replace `/media/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js` with `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js` and see if this fixes the problem. If it does, there is something wrong with your jQuery file.

Comment: you need to click on the input to bring up the calendar.

Comment: hello Wiliam. Thank you very much. I have changed my code **`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> ... <script type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $("#id_checkin").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); }); </script>`** The browser does not return errors this time, and the calendar shows itself. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mistake is on jquery function. Your date fields class is 'input', then jquery should be something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".input").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Comment: Hi Dani. Thank you very much for your reply. I have tryed the folowing: I have **`##'class':'input'`** and in the jquery function: **`$(function() {$("#checkin").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });`** The result is that firebug tells me that jQuery is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is following this trail, I had this same issue and resolved it.  Like the original poster, I was loading the JS in the `<head><script>` section.  It worked when I moved it out of that section and placed it at the bottom of the HTML

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />

<script>
    $(function() {
    $( ".datePicker" ).datepicker();  # change ".datePicker" to match your code
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This fixed it for me but I had to put 3 scripts at the bottom of my body: `moment.js`, `bootstrap.min.js`, and `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js`